# Hiding bootstrap modal from jQuery doesn't work the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having some problems with a JQuery code.
I'm trying to make a "dynamic" website, so every time you click on a link ('a' elements have a 'link' attribute), my code takes the 'link' attribute and passes it to jQuery's load() function. Thing is, I wanted to let the user know the content is loading, so I thought I could show a modal before start loading, and hiding it when finished, but it doesn't work. The first time I click on a link, modal stays there, and doesn't go away. However, from second time on, I click any link and everything works perfectly.

Why does it only fail to close the first time?

```
$(document).on("click", "[link]", function() {
    $("#cargando").modal('show');
    $('#contenido').load($(this).attr('link'), function() {
        $('#cargando').modal('hide');
        $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    });
});
```

Extra info: this code, and the modal HTML are together in a file named dyn.html, which is included at the end of the rest of the pages.

EDIT, modal code:

```
<div class="modal modal-static fade" id="cargando">
<div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body"><div class="text-center">
<h4>Cargando...</h4>
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

EDIT, it works with:

```
$(document).on("click", "[link]", function() {
$('#cargando').modal('show');
$('#contenido').load($(this).attr('link'), function() {
$('#cargando').hide();
$('.modal').hide();
$('.modal-backdrop').hide();
});
});
```

It's messy but it's the first thing that works.

Comment: Can you try replacing both  `modal('show')` and `modal('hide')` to `modal('toggle')`?

Comment: It loads two modals now. Every time. Sometimes more than two.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website, or reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: Please share the markup of the modal...there is probably something wrong there

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.modal').hide();
```

replace this code by applying timeout function. So it would be like.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.modal').hide();
},100);
```

Here 100 is the time out duration.

Comment: I've found this to work for me most of the time.
But why do we need to have this timeout? I have some other bootstrap events that need longer timeouts. I'm affraid users will start feeling it in my app. Why does it not work without this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been in this situation. But, here is what I found, I try to avoid using modal('show') when the modal wants to pop up, so what I prefer to do is to link the modal to an element and set the right attribute on that element and the modal will pop up.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

so try this one and let me know the result. Don't use the

```
$("#cargando").modal('show');
```

Comment: Same problem, but it's worth mentioning that the second line of the function works ("$('.modal-backdrop').hide();"). I've also tried to "force" it, by changing the display style to none, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you please not hide it from the jquery function please check this example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp. I think you're calling the hide function in a wrong place. If you could have provide us with your complete code it would have been better.

Comment: I believe the issue may stem from your click event bindings being nested. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631182/bootstrap-modal-button-click-event-not-fired-on-first-time?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

## update for bootstrap 3 and 4

```js
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#modal').modal('hide');
})
```